# How to obtain my PC lan card's IP address in PHP

Tags: php

I use the code below to display my IP and it is working just fine `

```
$host= gethostname();
$MyIp= gethostbyname($host);
echo $MyIp;
```

But my problem is that when both Lan and WiFi are connected, the code fetch the WiFi IP not the lan's. How to direct the code the the lan only?

Comment: PHP can't do this natively, it has no idea what IP it's listening on or (if there's more than one) which you prefer. If this is a script served by a web server (versus command-line) and the web server is IP-based instead of name-based, then 
 `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` will contain the IP that's answering the request -- which is presumably the LAN one because you would have set that in your web server's configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ip address you can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` this will get you the ip address that was used when the request was made.

PHP can't get you both ip addresses it will get you only the ip that was use when the request was made. The decision on which ip is used is based on your computer, it decides which one to use base on speed, connection or ip address(same network).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation .